# Multiple converts from one source using imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, graphicsmagick

Is it possible to have one source and from that have 2 types of processed images with different configurations? (and not to read the source image twice)?

Something like

```
convert input.jpg -resize 300 output1.jpg -resize 600 output2.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, use an intermediate `-write` like this, and do the big one first:

```
convert input.jpg -resize 600 -write im600.jpg -resize 300 im300.jpg
```

Or, if you want to start afresh with each operation:

```
convert input.png \
  \( +clone -resize 300 -write result300.jpg \) \
  \( +clone -resize 600 -write result600.jpg \) null:
```

If using GraphicsMagick, I am not sure if there is a better way than the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
{ echo convert input.png mpr:orig; 
  echo convert mpr:orig -resize 300 result300.jpg;
  echo convert mpr:orig -resize 600 result600.jpg; } | gm batch -prompt off
```

This is a slightly different version that only invokes `convert` twice:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat - <<EOF | gm batch -prompt off
convert input.png -write mpr:orig -resize 300 result300.jpg
convert mpr:orig -resize 600 result600.jpg
EOF
```

Comment: won't this be something like `source -> 600 -> 300` and not `source -> 300` and `source -> 600`

Comment: Yes, it will. I have added a version that starts each operation afresh rather than carrying on from the previous position.

Comment: Thanks! Why is the null necessary?

Comment: The null is there because the original image, and the clones, are still in the stack of images to process so I just discard everything to null, since I have already generated all the output files I want using `-write`.

Comment: You can do something pretty similar, but **GraphicsMagick** does not offer `+clone` or parentheses, so the best I can do is via `MPR` which is a RAM based copy.